# SQL: Return immediately if one matched record found

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have one table with user and their posts. It looks like "user_id | post_id | post_status".

Now I have a list of userid (ex, 100 users) and I want to know how many of them has at least one post that gets deleted (ex, post_status 3).

Here is my sample search:

```
select count(distinct user_id) 
from post_table 
where user_id in ( {my set} ) 
  and post_status=3
```

It runs super slow since it iterates the entire table. Is there a way to speed up the query?

Comment: The title and the question seem slightly different in their intent

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
-- the list of userid as a rowset
     ( SELECT 123 AS user_id UNION ALL
       SELECT 456            UNION ALL
       -- ...
       SELECT 789
       ) user_id_list
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM post_table 
               WHERE post_table.user_id = user_id_list.user_id
                 AND post_table.post_status = 3 )
```

If your MySQL version is 8.0.4 or above then you may provide the users list as CSV/JSON and parse it using JSON_TABLE (the query text will be more compact).

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX(post_status, user_id)
```

may help speed up your query, especially if very few rows have status=3.

This could also speed up Akina's solution.